# validate a path structure ending in a filename.xml

Tags: regex

I'm having trouble with a regular expression. Hope someone can help or point in right direction. Essentially I've to validate a path structure.

The rules for valid input to my method are:

1. (including the forward slash) starts with /usersname/
2. must only be one occurrence of /usersname/
3. after the one occurrence of /usersname/  there must only be one [aphanumeric-_ space].xml

So for example, the following are valid input into my method:

- `/norrisc/thesf6457.xml`
- `/norrisc/thess63-57.xml`
- `/norrisc/thqsf64-57 gdhy.xml`
- `/norrisc/ase45tg_3.xml`

.. and the following are *in*valid input into method:

- `/norrisc/anotherFolder/thesf6457.xml`
- `/norrisc/norrisc/thess63-57.xml`
- `/norrisc/norrisc/thess63-57.txt`
- `/norrisc/norrisc/thess63-57`
- `/norrisc/thqsf64-57 gdhy.xml/kjhfsd.xml`

My efforts (to no avail) so far are..

- `\b[/username/]{1}^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\s-]+$\.xml`
- `^[/username/]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_\\s-]+$\.xml{1}`
- `\b/username/{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_\\s-]+$\.xml{1}`

Hope someone can help.. ?

Thanks v much

Comment: I'm not sure regex is the right choice here. You could simply split your string by the '/' delimiter. If there's more than 2 values OR the first value is not the username OR the last value is not valid (doesn't end with xml OR contains characters that are not valid) then your input is invalid, otherwise it is valid.

Comment: i dunno @halflings, if you're comfortable using a regex for this, i don't think there's necessarily a *good* reason not to (i probably wouldn't for something simple like this though). it will certainly work just as well as splitting the string, so it's up to personal preference or whichever way fits best with the rest of the code. if they're already using regexes to validate everything, a regex probably *would* be the best choice.

Comment: True. But it's clear that following a "naive" approach (with tokens) would've saved the OP many headaches. Also, that would make his code more maintainable. (but this is probably just my anti-regex-everywhere bias)

Comment: **This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.


Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me on your test cases:

```
^\/username\/(?!.*\/)(\w|\s|-)+\.xml$
```

where `username`, obviously, is the literal username or a variable containing it.

Breaking that down ...

- `^` - start of string
- `\/username\/` - literal username enclosed by `/`
- `(?!.*\/)` - negative lookahead: ensures the rest of the string does not contain another `/`
- `(\w|\s|-)+` - one or more letters, digits, spaces, `_`, or `-`
- `\.xml` - literal `.xml`
- `$` - end of string

If you're unfamiliar with lookaheads, the `(?=)` structure lets you match using a *zero-width assertion*. For example, `(?=a)` would attempt to recognize an `a` character but will NOT include it as part of the match (that's what "zero-width" means— `^` and `$` are other examples of zero-width assertions). This is called a **positive lookahead** and lets you "skip over" characters in a sense.

`(?!)` does the same thing, but checks if the specified pattern does *not* exist. It's called a **negative lookahead**. So in the regex above, `(?!.*\/)` looks for the `.*\/` pattern, which means "any or zero character(s) followed by a slash". If it finds this, such as in the string `/username/another_username/whatever.xml`, the match will NOT succeed (because the lookahead is *negative*).

Comment: Thank you very much for that response.. and also the excellent explanation of the detail. Yes, I tried a string tok method (i'm using java) but I feel my life as a programmer will improve if I can become proficient in reg expressions.

Comment: glad to help. yeah, regex is a great tool that will definitely help you as a programmer. it's used by a wide variety of other languages/tools (such as `vi`) and tends to make certain tasks a lot faster if you're good at writing patterns. funnily enough, i don't find myself using regexes much in my actual programs - they're more of a tool that goes great with a *nix command line to speed up the non-coding parts to your work (quickly trimming an error log down to the lines you need, for example)